# How to modify login php script for Client Area

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have this php script which redirects users to specific pages based on there username and password.

Once you're logged in and redirected to your page, then leave (go to the home page for example) and then click on client login again to return to your page, a message pops up saying you are already logged in click here to view your page.  How do I get it to just redirect back to the page of the logged in user?

If your have trouble understanding, please visit my site to see it (user: tyler pass: tyler for the login info) [splitlinemedia.com](http://www.splitlinemedia.com)

login.php

```
<?php
    if(!defined("SESSION")){
    session_start();
    define("SESSION", true);
 }
    if(isset($_GET["log_out"])){
    unset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);
    header('refresh: 3; url=login.php');
    echo "You're logged out, and will be redirected in about 3 seconds";
    exit;
 }

 $login = true;
 require "protect.php";

 $logins[0]["user"] = "tyler";
 $logins[0]["pass"] = "tyler";
 $logins[0]["redirect"] = "test.php";

 $logins[1]["user"] = "x";
 $logins[1]["pass"] = "y";
 $logins[1]["redirect"] = "z.php";

  // No need to edit below, except the errors

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //is the form submitted?
   if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
     echo "You have to fill out the user name and password!";
     exit;
   } //check for empty user name or password
   $is_logged = false; 
   foreach($logins as $login){
      $user = $_POST;
      if(($user["user"] == $login["user"]) && ($user["pass"] == $login["pass"])) {
         $is_logged = true;
         $_SESSION["logged_in"] = array($login["redirect"], true); 
         header("Location: ".$login["redirect"]);
     exit;
     }
 }
 if(!$is_logged){ echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Inncorect username or     password");window.history.go(-1);</script>'; } 
 }
 ?>
```

protect.php

```
<?php
if(!defined("SESSION")){
   session_start();
   define("SESSION", true);
}
   if((!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) || !$_SESSION["logged_in"][1]){
     if(!isset($login)){
        header("Location: login.php"); //check to see if logged in, otherwise go to the login
    exit;
   }
  } else if (isset($login) || isset($index)){
  echo "Your already logged in!! <a href='login.php?log_out'>Click here</a>, to logout.   Or, go back to your <a href='{$_SESSION['logged_in'][0]}'>page</a>.";
  exit;
 }
?>
```

Then this at the top of my test.php page

```
<?php
include("protect.php");
?>
```

Comment: you can redirect a user, using `header(Location:http://example.com)` , replace example.com with required url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

```
<?php
if(!defined("SESSION")){
session_start();
define("SESSION", true);
}
 if((!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) || !$_SESSION["logged_in"][1]){
 if(!isset($login)){
 header("Location: login.php"); //check to see if logged in, otherwise go to the login
exit;
}
} else if (isset($login) || isset($index)){
header("Location: " . $_SESSION['logged_in'][0]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **protect.php** simply replace the **echo** line that says they are already logged in with a header redirect line such as: `header("Location: ".$_SESSION['logged_in'][0]);`